# VBA to loop through values in column, place values in cell that affects formula, and copy and paste resultant formula to adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

Not super knowledgeable with VBA, but I'm assuming/hoping this is a fairly simple question. I have a worksheet where column K has any values that can be input in cell E1. Cell B25 contains a simple formula (=$B$24-$B$8), but is affected by other formulas, which depend on the value in cell E1.

What I need is for E1 to be looped through with the values in column K and paste the calculated value in B25 in column L for each value in column K. I have 2 VBA codes that I'm working with, but neither of them are working exactly how we need them to.

```
Sub Check()
Dim c As Range, sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each c In sh1.Range("K2", Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))
        sh1.Range("E1") = c.Value
        sh1.Range("B25", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Copy
        sh1.Range("L2", Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
         Next
End Sub
```

And

```
        Sub Check2()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, c As Range
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each c In sh1.Range("K2", sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))
            sh1.Range("E1") = c.Value
            sh1.Range("B25", sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, 2)).Copy _
            sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp)(2)
        Next

End Sub
```

The first code loops through E1 and posts the calculated value of B25 in cell L2 only, so there's no way for us to know which corresponding item in column K it's referencing.

The second code is closer. It posts the results of the formula in column L sequentially, but it recalculates for each instance of the looped column K value in E1, meaning that ultimately the result of the formula in B25 will post the results only corresponding to the final value of column K in column L (i.e. the formula =$B$24-$B$8 is copied and pasted down column L for every value in column K but the last value of column K will be in cell E1, so that's what the formula is referring to).

I might be going about this all wrong, but as mentioned, I don't deal with VBA a lot. I hope someone can help me with this, but please let me know if I was unclear in my request or anyone needs more information!

Comment: All you need do is in the second version use pastespecial values, as in the first version.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax (as mentioned, don't use VBA a lot). When I put the paste clause in after the '(2)', it gives me a compile error: "expected end of statement" and highlights in red. If I try to run despite the error, it gives "syntax error." I totally understand what you're saying intuitively (it's more-or-less what I initially tried to do), but do you know the correct syntax?

Comment: The PS bit needs to be on a new line as you have done before.

Comment: Thanks again, but if it isn't too much trouble, could you please share the exact syntax? I've tried a few different combinations. I can get it to no longer give the syntax error by starting a new line, as you stated, but if I run on the workbook level, I get  the "application-defined or object-defined" error. If I run on the module level, I get the "PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed" error.

Comment: I've added some code but what do you mean by "run on the workbook level"?

Comment: The code below works perfectly; thanks so much! Looks like I needed to delete the underscore, and then change the Paste Special syntax a little bit. Thanks again! On the "workbook" level, I was trying to distinguish between running it in "Modules" and running it in my open workbook from "This Workbook"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub Check2()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, c As Range

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each c In sh1.Range("K2", sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))
    sh1.Range("E1") = c.Value
    sh1.Range("B25", sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, 2)).Copy
    sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlValues
Next

End Sub
```